# Segmented Progressbar in C#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I want to use a segmented progressbar to show download status in my application. For example:

[image]

Does anyone know how to implement it in C#? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would consider using `System.Drawing` and handle the `OnPaint` event.  There is a good tutorial on custom `ProgressBar` creation [Here](http://tutplusplus.blogspot.com/2010/09/c-tutorial-create-custom-progressbar.html).

Comment: Does it indicate progress, e.g. the hue changes to indicate the remaining work, or does it just dance so the user will assume that something is going on?

Comment: @Evanlewis Thanks for the link, it was great help. As pointed out by HABO, I will have to work on hue change animation (similar to common progress-bar) so that users know that the app is not hanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MyDownloader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21053/MyDownloader-A-Multi-thread-C-Segmented-Download-M) project on CodeProject implements a segmented ProgressBar that does just that. Here's the control implementation (copied here in case the project gets deleted):

```
// The following code was written by Guilherme Labigalini
public partial class BlockedProgressBar : Control
{
    BlockList _blockList;

    /// <summary>
    /// MyProgressBar Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public BlockedProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _blockList = new BlockList();
        _direction = DirectionMode.Horizontal;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Update mode of segments
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The mode of update of progress bar")]
    [Category("MyProgressBar")]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public BlockList.UpdateMode UpdateMode
    {
        get { return _blockList.Update; }
        set { _blockList.Update = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change quantity of segments
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The length of segments of progress bar")]
    [Category("MyProgressBar")]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public int Length
    {
        get { return _blockList.Length; }
        set { _blockList.Length = value; this.Refresh(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set filled segments 
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public int[] FilledSegments
    {
        get { return _blockList.FilledSegments; }
        set { _blockList.FilledSegments = value; this.Refresh(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or sets the full list of segments
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public bool[] FullListSegment
    {
        get { return _blockList.FullListSegment; }
        set { _blockList.FullListSegment = value; this.Refresh(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set the block list of segments
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public List<Block> BlockList
    {
        get { return _blockList.List; }
        set { _blockList.List = value; this.Refresh(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// DirectionMode of bar
    /// </summary>
    public enum DirectionMode
    {
        Horizontal = 0,
        Vertical = 1
    }
    private DirectionMode _direction = DirectionMode.Horizontal;
    /// <summary>
    /// Horizontal or Vertical
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The filling direction of progress bar")]
    [Category("MyProgressBar")]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public DirectionMode Direction
    {
        get { return _direction; }
        set { _direction = value; this.Refresh(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// OnPaint event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pe"></param>
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Color color1 = ControlPaint.Dark(this.ForeColor);
        Color color2 = ControlPaint.Light(this.ForeColor);

        if (_direction == DirectionMode.Horizontal)
        {
            int top = ClientRectangle.Top + ClientRectangle.Height / 2 - 1;
            int height = ClientRectangle.Height - top;
            DrawRectangleH(pe, top, height, color2, color1);

            top = ClientRectangle.Top;
            height = ClientRectangle.Height / 2;
            DrawRectangleH(pe, top, height, color1, color2);
        }
        else
        {
            int left = ClientRectangle.Left;
            int width = ClientRectangle.Width / 2;
            DrawRectangleV(pe, left, width, color1, color2);

            left = ClientRectangle.Left + ClientRectangle.Width / 2;
            width = ClientRectangle.Width / 2;
            DrawRectangleV(pe, left, width, color2, color1);
        }

        pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), ClientRectangle);
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
    private void DrawRectangleH(PaintEventArgs pe, int top, int height, Color fromColor, Color toColor)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Left, top, ClientRectangle.Width, height);
        var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, fromColor, toColor, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
        if (_blockList.Length > 0)
        {
            Rectangle[] rects = GetRectanglesH(top, height);
            if (rects.Length > 0) pe.Graphics.FillRectangles(brush, rects); //SystemBrushes.Control
        }
    }
    private void DrawRectangleV(PaintEventArgs pe, int left, int width, Color fromColor, Color toColor)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(left, ClientRectangle.Top, width, ClientRectangle.Height);
        var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, fromColor, toColor, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
        if (_blockList.Length > 0)
        {
            Rectangle[] rects = GetRectanglesV(left, width);
            if (rects.Length > 0) pe.Graphics.FillRectangles(brush, rects); //SystemBrushes.Control
        }
    }
    private Rectangle[] GetRectanglesH(int top, int height)
    {
        var rects = new List<Rectangle>();
        float xf = 0;
        int y = top;
        int h = height;

        float pf = this.Width / (float)_blockList.Length;
        //h = this.Height;

        foreach (Block block in _blockList.List)
        {
            if (block.PercentProgress > 0)
            {
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(xf);
                float wf = (pf * (block.BlockSize * block.PercentProgress / 100)) + xf - x;
                int w = Convert.ToInt32(wf);

                rects.Add(new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
            }

            xf += pf * block.BlockSize;
        }
        return rects.ToArray();
    }

    private Rectangle[] GetRectanglesV(int left, int width)
    {
        var rects = new List<Rectangle>();
        float yf = 0;
        int x = left;
        int w = width;

        float pf = this.Height / (float)_blockList.Length;
        //w = this.Width;

        foreach (Block block in _blockList.List)
        {
            if (block.PercentProgress > 0)
            {
                int y = Convert.ToInt32(yf);
                float hf = (pf * (block.BlockSize * block.PercentProgress / 100)) + yf - y;
                int h = Convert.ToInt32(hf);

                rects.Add(new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
            }

            yf += pf * block.BlockSize;
        }
        return rects.ToArray();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class BlockList
{
    private int _length;
    private List<Block> _blockList;

    public BlockList()
    {
        _blockList = new List<Block>();
    }

    public enum UpdateMode
    {
        All,
        FilledSegments,
        FullListSegment,
        BlockList
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update mode of segments
    /// </summary>
    public UpdateMode Update = UpdateMode.All;

    /// <summary>
    /// Change quantity of segments
    /// </summary>
    public int Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
        set
        {
            if (_length != value && value > 0)
            {
                var bools = FullListSegment;
                var bools2 = new bool[value];
                for (int i = 0; i < bools.Length; i++)
                {
                    bools2[i] = bools[i];
                }
                FullListSegment = bools2;
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set filled segments 
    /// </summary>
    public int[] FilledSegments
    {
        get
        {
            var bools = FullListSegment;
            var filled = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < bools.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bools[i])
                {
                    filled.Add(i);
                }

            }
            return filled.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (Update != UpdateMode.All && Update != UpdateMode.FilledSegments)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            if (value != null)
                if (value.Length > 0)
                {
                    var bools = FullListSegment;
                    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                    {
                        bools.SetValue(true, value[i]);
                    }
                    FullListSegment = bools;
                }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or sets the full list of segments
    /// </summary>
    public bool[] FullListSegment
    {
        get
        {
            int sizeAnterior = 0;
            var bools = new bool[_length];
            if (bools.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (Block block in _blockList)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(block.BlockSize * block.PercentProgress / 100); i++)
                        bools.SetValue(true, i + sizeAnterior);
                    sizeAnterior += Convert.ToInt32(block.BlockSize);
                }
            }
            return bools;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Update != UpdateMode.All && Update != UpdateMode.FullListSegment)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            bool bOld = false;
            int qtd = 0;
            int filled = 0;
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.Length > 0)
                {
                    _blockList.Clear();
                    float percent;
                    foreach (bool b in value)
                    {
                        if (b == bOld)
                            qtd++;
                        else
                        {
                            if (bOld)
                                filled = qtd;
                            else if (filled + qtd > 0)
                            {
                                percent = filled / (float)(filled + qtd) * 100;
                                _blockList.Add(new Block(filled + qtd, percent));
                            }
                            qtd = 1;
                            bOld = b;
                        }
                    }
                    if (filled + qtd > 0)
                    {
                        percent = filled / (float)(filled + qtd) * 100;
                        _blockList.Add(new Block(filled + qtd, percent));
                    }
                    _length = value.Length;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _length = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set the block list of segments
    /// </summary>
    public List<Block> List
    {
        get
        {
            return _blockList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Update != UpdateMode.All && Update != UpdateMode.BlockList)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            float size = 0;
            _blockList = value;
            if (_blockList != null)
                size += _blockList.Sum(block => block.BlockSize);
            _length = Convert.ToInt32(size);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Block
{
    private float _blockSize;
    private float _percentProgress;

    public Block(float blockSize, float percentProgress)
    {
        this.BlockSize = blockSize;
        this.PercentProgress = percentProgress;
    }

    public float BlockSize
    {
        get { return _blockSize; }
        set { _blockSize = value; }
    }

    public float PercentProgress
    {
        get { return _percentProgress; }
        set { _percentProgress = value; }
    }
}
```

And here's how to use it :

```
blockedProgressBar1.BlockList = new List<Block>(5)
            {
                new Block(100,20),
                new Block(100,50),
                new Block(100,70),
                new Block(100,99),
                new Block(100,60),
                new Block(100,35),
            };
```

And here's how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I have make the same application but progress bar not displaying. any reason?

Comment: @Chirag it should work (at least, it did last time I used that snippet). If you're having problems with then you should ask a question.

Comment: `@Nasreddine` - the code is working fine, but the progressbar didn't displayed.